# Rails - Get Column Value with Group By

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, group-by

I have the following tables with entries that might look like:

```
 Table: sessions

 ID | CREATED_AT              | UPDATED_AT              | USER_ID | GROUP_ID 
 ---|-------------------------|-------------------------|---------|----------  
 27 | 2014-07-01 23:02:16     | 2014-07-01 23:03:18     | 1       | 1     
 28 | 2014-07-02 16:55:25     | 2014-07-02 17:31:40     | 1       | 2       
 29 | 2014-07-07 20:31:13     | 2014-07-07 20:34:17     | 1       | 3        

 Table: groups

 ID | NAME              | CREATED_AT              | UPDATED_AT             
 ---|-------------------|-------------------------|------------------------
 1  | Marching          | 2013-12-17 19:45:28     | 2013-12-17 19:45:28    
 2  | Reaching          | 2014-02-07 17:29:59     | 2014-02-07 17:29:59    
 3  | Picking           | 2014-03-11 21:38:56     | 2014-03-11 21:38:56
```

And I have the following query in Rails:

```
 Session.joins(:group).select('groups.name').where(:user_id => 1).group('sessions.group_id').count
```

Which returns the following keys and values:

```
  => {2=>7, 1=>3, 3=>1}  (The "key" is the group_id and the "value"
                          is the # of times it occurs).
```

**My question is:** Instead of returning the "id" as the key, is it possible for me to return the `groups.name` instead?  Which would look like:

```
  => {"Reaching"=>7, "Marching"=>3, "Picking"=>1}
```

If not, would I have to loop through and re-query again based on each `group_id`?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you have everything set up in your models.

```
data = Group.joins(:sessions).select('name, count(*) as occurrence_count').where('sessions.user_id = ?', 1).group('groups.name')
```

Then you can access it like this

```
data.first.occurrence_count
```

Comment: Hi Iceman, thanks for your response.  I'm getting this error with your query `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "groups.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.  I'm pretty sure my models are set up correctly.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually read the error message (what a concept?), and changed the `group()` to `group('groups.name')` which appeared to clean it up.  Thanks!